# How to detect a touch of admob banner ads in ios

Tags: ios, admob

I am new in iOS game development.I am developing a kids app and into that app I am integrating admob ads.I have to detect touch event when user click on ads.Because when user click on that ads user first show a parental control.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Which SDK are you using? Assuming 6.11.1 (latest), normally you should implement your class as a delegate for GADBannerViewDelegate or GADInterstitialDelegate (reffer to [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/banner#ad_lifecycle_event_callbacks)):

YourClass.h:

```
@interface YourClass : SuperClass <GADBannerViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate> {
}
```

YourClass.m:

```
// onAdOpened
- (void)adViewWillPresentScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    <your code here>
}

// onAdLeftApplication
- (void)adViewWillLeaveApplication:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    <your code here>
}
```